# SQL Difference between using two dates

Tags: sql, oracle

My database has a table called 'clientordermas'. Two columns of that table are as follows.

execid and filledqty.
Three records of those two fields are as follows.

> E02011/03/12-05:57_24384    : 1000
>   E02011/03/12-05:57_24384    :  800
>   E02011/03/09-05:57_24384    :   600

What i need to do is get the filledqty diffrence btween latest date and 1 before latest date which is 400(1000-400).
I have extracted the date from the execid as follows:

> (SUBSTR (execid, 3, 10)

I tried so hard but but I was unable to write the sql query to get 400. Can someone please help me to do this???

P.S I need to select maximum filled quantity from the same date. That is 1000 not, 800.

Comment: How do you know it's 400 (1000-600) and not 200 (800-600)? The first two dates are identical. Is there some other ordering?

Comment: Yeh. Sorry I couldn't mention it. I need to get maximum value of filled quentity from same date.

Comment: @ganuke, I think you are still struggling. Looks like you haven't been able to clearly define your problem and what you want accomplished.  If you give a clear description of what data is available, and what *exactly* you want to achieve, maybe people can really help you instead of shooting in the dark *guessing* what you want.

Comment: @ganuke, perhaps you are looking to: (1) get the maximum filledqty for each unique date, (2) calculate the difference between the last date and the 2nd last date?

Comment: @ Stephen.actually it is 2nd one. calculate the difference between the last date and the 2nd last date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions to access "nearby" rows, so if you first clean up the data in a subquery and then use window functions to access the next row, you should get the right results. But unless you have an index on `substr(execid, 3, 10)`, this is going to be be slow.

```
WITH datevalues AS
(
  SELECT max(filledqty) maxfilledqty, substr(execid, 3, 10) execiddate
  FROM clientordermas
  GROUP BY substr(execid, 3, 10)
)
SELECT
  execiddate,
  maxfilledqty -
  last_value(maxfilledqty) over(ORDER BY execiddate DESC ROWS BETWEEN 0 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING)
FROM datevalues
ORDER BY execiddate DESC;
```

Comment: It doesnt working properly. I removed the minus part from the query. Then it shows 1000(when rownum=1). But it shows nothing when rownum =2. where is the problem. when I run the query inside the first parenthesis it shows 1000 and 600 with relevant dates.

Comment: Hm, you are right. Use the second query and take only the first row, that should work.

Comment: It works fine. But I need only one record. Which is difference between only two most latest days. Your one shows three records. Can you pls tell me how to do get only first record. Thanks in advance

Comment: Window functions are only supported by Oracle, so it might be better to stick with standard SQL as much as possible (although the WITH clause is also Oracle) -- easier to move to another database engine.

Comment: @Stephen Chung I think that's fairly backwards approach. If you are paying $$$ for a database and it has some features that result in the most efficient solution, use it! Besides, both WITH and windows functions are standard SQL (just not the ancient version) and many other databases support them (MS-SQL, PostgreSQL).

Comment: @ganuke `SELECT * FROM (...) WHERE rownum=1`

Comment: @Lukáš Lalinský you're right!  Ma bad!  WITH and window functions **are** standard SQL, just not implemented everywhere.  I've checked that they are also implemented in SQL Server.  +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH maxqtys AS (
SELECT substr(a.execid,3,10) AS date, MAX(a.filledqty) AS maxqty
FROM clientordermas a
GROUP BY substr(a.execid,3,10)
)
SELECT a.maxqty-b.maxqty
FROM maxqtys a, maxqtys b
WHERE a.date <> b.date AND ROWNUM=1
ORDER BY a.date DESC, b.date DESC
```

This first creates a subquery (maxqty) which contains the max filledqty for each unique date, then cross join this subquery to itself, excluding the same rows.  This results in a table containing pairs of dates (excluding the same dates).

Sort these pairs by date descending, and the top row till contain the last and 2nd-to-last date, with the appropriate quantities.